# group by JSon in node for uniqu id

Tags: node.js

In my nodeJs code I am fetching some records from database. I am getting the data as JSON as below:

```
[[{
    sourcePguid: '000526420800003',
    recordPguid: 'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000011225'
  },
  {
    sourcePguid: '000526420800003',
    recordPguid: 'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000011225'
  }]
  ]
```

What I want is something like the following JSON:

```
{
    sourcePguid: '000526420800003',
    recordPguid:['urn:reference:000000000000000000000000011225','urn:reference:000000000000000000000000011225']

  }
```

I am new to java scripts and node. Kindly if any one help me to achieve the output in node JS.

Comment: 1. Is your data really an array of arrays? If yes, what happens if it has multiple arrays? 2. What have you tried? Some code showing your attempt will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to flat whole array

```js
const array = [[{
    sourcePguid: '000526420800003',
    recordPguid: 'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000011225'
  },
  {
    sourcePguid: '000526420800003',
    recordPguid: 'urn:reference:000000000000000000000000011225'
  }]
].flat();
```

Next you need to reduce the array grouping by some key

```js
const grouped = array.reduce((all, current) => {
  const existing = all.find(element => element.sourcePguid === current.sourcePguid);
  if (!existing) {
    all.push({sourcePguid: current.sourcePguid, recordPguid: [current.recordPguid]});
  } else if (!existing.recordPguid.find(record => record === current.recordPguid)) {
    existing.recordPguid.push(current.recordPguid);
  }
  return all;
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks Its working fine .if there is duplicate recordPguid i need to remove that .How to add a condition in that .